# Калькулятор просчета стоимости в зависимости от выбранног select

Tags: javascript, html, input

Пытаюсь написать калькулятор. Нужно посчитать стоимость в зависимости от выбранного select. Но не получается отследить изменения в select. Буду благодарен за помощь)

```js
const dataInput = document.querySelector("#data-input");
const resultInput = document.querySelector("#result-input");
const select = document.querySelector("#select");

dataInput.oninput = function() {
  if (select.value === "Value-1") {
    dataInput.oninput = function() {
      resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 2).toFixed(2);
    };
  } else if (select.value === "Value-2") {
    dataInput.oninput = function() {
      resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 3).toFixed(2);
    };
  } else if (select.value === "Value-3") {
    dataInput.oninput = function() {
      resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 4).toFixed(2);
    };
  } else if (select.value === "Value-4") {
    dataInput.oninput = function() {
      resultInput.value = parseFloat(dataInput.value * 5).toFixed(2);
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrapp">
  <div class="input">
    <select id="select">
      <option value="Value-1">Value-1</option>
      <option value="Value-2">Value-2</option>
      <option value="Value-3">Value-3</option>
      <option value="Value-4">Value-4</option>
    </select>
    <input id="data-input">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <p class="result-title">Результат:</p>
    <input id="result-input" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const select = document.querySelector("#select");
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  dataInput.oninput();
});
```

```js
const dataInput = document.querySelector("#data-input");
const resultInput = document.querySelector("#result-input");
const select = document.querySelector("#select");

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  dataInput.oninput();
});

dataInput.oninput = function() {
  if (select.value === "Value-1") {
    resultInput.value = (dataInput.value * 2).toFixed(2);
  } else if (select.value === "Value-2") {
    resultInput.value = (dataInput.value * 3).toFixed(2);
  } else if (select.value === "Value-3") {
    resultInput.value = (dataInput.value * 4).toFixed(2);
  } else if (select.value === "Value-4") {
    resultInput.value = (dataInput.value * 5).toFixed(2);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="calc-wrapp">
  <div class="input">
    <select id="select">
      <option value="Value-1">Value-1</option>
      <option value="Value-2">Value-2</option>
      <option value="Value-3">Value-3</option>
      <option value="Value-4">Value-4</option>
    </select>
    <input id="data-input">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <p class="result-title">Результат:</p>
    <input id="result-input" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) А Вы знаете как сделать, чтобы сразу input отслеживал ввод? А то нужно переключится на какой-то option, чтобы оно умножило

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @ross333 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Почему бы вам через кнопку "править" не улучшить этот ответ и показать как нужно? Или просто легче минус поставить?)

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, [хорошие примеры, на которые стоит ориентироваться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa). // я уже не один месяц пытаюсь убедить пользователя Igor писать более развёрнутые ответы. иногда он так и делает. и я с радостью ставлю такому ответу «плюс». но, естественно, я не слежу специально ни за этим пользователем, ни за любым другим — движок сам помещает низкокачественные ответы в соответствующую очередь проверки.